# How do I save image file into java project file location from JFileChooser?

Tags: java, save, file-location

I am retrieving an image file with the following lines of code...

How do I make sure it ends up in the project file location?

```
public void run() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png"));
    while (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();  
            BufferedImage thisImage = ImageIO.read(f);
        }
    }
}
```

I assume I am supposed to use ImageIO.write() in some way?? Nothing I have dont works.

Two things I've tried:

```
Files.copy(f.toPath(), new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

`ImageIO.write(thisImage, "png", f);`

Comment: What do you mean by "the project file location"? Do you mean where the code is executing from?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to accomplish.  If you want to make an image viewer, you don’t need to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` will return the path for the current working dir. I'm assuming that's what you mean. Then it's just using what you suggested to write the file out.

```
var workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
var outputfile = new File(workingDir + "/saved.png");
ImageIO.write(yourBufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
```

Something like that anyway.

Comment: all I am looking for is a way to use a JFileChooser to retrieve a file from my PC, and programmatically save it as a file inside the source folder of a java project.